# How to write all request.form[] data in one line python flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I have an flask API call. Here I have a `request.form` data.
It looks like this:

```
id = request.form['id']
username = request.form['username']
password = request.form['password']
dbname = request.form['dbname']
tablename = request.form['tablename']
```

I want to write it in a single line in python. I tried this way but it shows error.

```
id,username,password,dbname,tablename = request.form['token','username','password','dbname','tablename']
```

I tried this. it showing error. How to achieve this...I want this to be in a single line. Is it possible in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator expression:

```
id, username, password, dbname, tablename = (request.form[s] for s in ('token', 'username', 'password', 'dbname', 'tablename'))
```

Map:

```
id, username, password, dbname, tablename = map(request.form.get, ('token', 'username', 'password', 'dbname', 'tablename'))
```